# how store php array to redis and retrieve in nodejs?

Tags: php, node.js, redis

I use `redis` (predis/predis composer) to save some id in php like this:

```
$redis = new Client();
$mailJson = $redis->get('mail');
$mail  = json_decode($mailJson);
$no = rand(100,500);
array_push($mail, $no);
$redis->set('mail', json_encode($mail));
```

and i retrieve this array like this:

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();
client.on('connect', function() {
    client.get('mail', function(err, mailIds) {
        console.log(mailIds);
    });
});
```

But `mailIds` variable is string and not an array like this:

```
[1,200,500,500,400,100,200,100]
```

Is way can access `mailIds` items ?

Comment: you need to use "json_decode". it will recreate an array from your JSON-string. JSON is always a string describing an array/object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the json (a string) so that you get an array in javascript / node.js:

```
client.get('mail', function(err, mailIds) {
    // parse the json
    mailIdsArray = JSON.parse(mailIds);
    console.log(mailIdsArray);
});
```